# jQuery not working on ie7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a piece of jQuery on this page - http://blackeaglemedia.co.uk/cs-cart/form/preterm.htm

The expected result should show the part number field built up as the user makes selections.

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE9, but it doesn't appear to be working in IE7 or IE8.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
var sku1 = sku2 = sku3 = sku4 = sku5 = sku6 = length = '';
$("#options").change(function(){

    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3134":
             sku1 = 'TB';
        break;
        case "3135":
             sku1 = 'LT';
        break;
        case "3154":
            sku1 = 'LTR';
        break;
        case "3136":
             sku1 = 'BO';
        break;
        case "3138":
             sku1 = 'MC';
        break;
        case "3139":
             sku1 = 'NC';
        break;
        case "3183":
              sku1 = 'STA';
        break;
    }$('#sku').val(sku3+sku2+sku5+sku4+sku1+sku6+length);
});
$("#options2").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3111":
              sku2 = 'LC';
        break;
        case "3110":
             sku2 ='LCA';
        break;
        case "3112":
             sku2 ='E2000';
        break;
        case "3113":
             sku2 ='E2A';
        break;
        case "3114":
             sku2 ='FC';
        break;
        case "3115":
             sku2 ='FCA';
        break;
        case "3116":
             sku2 ='ST';
        break;
        case "3117":
             sku2 ='SC';
        break;
        case "3118":
             sku2 ='SCA';
        break;
    } $('#sku').val(sku3+sku2+sku5+sku4+sku1+sku6+length);
});
$("#options3").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3175":
             sku3 = 'PRE2';
        break;
        case "3121":
             sku3 ='PRE4';
        break;
        case "3122":
             sku3 ='PRE6';
        break;
        case "3123":
             sku3 ='PRE8';
        break;
        case "3124":
             sku3 ='PRE12';
        break;
        case "3125":
             sku3 ='PRE16';
        break;
        case "3126":
             sku3 ='PRE24';
        break;
        case "3176":
             sku3 ='PRE48';
        break;
    } $('#sku').val(sku3+sku2+sku5+sku4+sku1+sku6+length);
});

$("#options4").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3127":
              sku4 = '09';
        break;
        case "3182":
             sku4 ='G657A1';
        break;
        case "3128":
             sku4 ='62';
        break;
        case "3129":
             sku4 ='50';
        break;
        case "3130":
             sku4 ='OM3';
        break;
        case "3131":
             sku4 ='OM4';
        break;
    } $('#sku').val(sku3+sku2+sku5+sku4+sku1+sku6+length);
});

$("#options5").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3142":
              sku5 = 'LC';
        break;
        case "3143":
             sku5 ='LCA';
        break;
        case "3144":
             sku5 ='E2000';
        break;
        case "3145":
             sku5 ='E2A';
        break;
        case "3146":
             sku5 ='FC';
        break;
        case "3147":
             sku5 ='FCA';
        break;
        case "3148":
             sku5 ='ST';
        break;
        case "3149":
             sku5 ='SC';
        break;
        case "3150":
             sku5 ='SCA';
        break;
    } $('#sku').val(sku3+sku2+sku5+sku4+sku1+sku6+length);
});

$("#options6").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "3151":
              sku6 = 'LZSH';
        break;
        case "3177":
              sku6 ='PE';
        break;
    } $('#sku').val(sku3+sku2+sku5+sku4+sku1+sku6+length);
});

$('#length').change(function(){
    length = $(this).val(); $('#sku').val(sku3+sku2+sku5+sku4+sku1+sku6+length);
});
});

$(function() {
    $('input[type=text]#length').focus(function() {
      $(this).val('');
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should consider reworking your code. It's unnecessarily long with some code duplication. It could probably be simplified to 10 lines or less.

Especially you should use objects (as hash tables) instead of switches or store the "SKU"s directly in the options.

Secondly you should look at the error message that IE provides, preferably in the console in Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd> > Script > Console), which will you give a hint what (or at least where) the error is.

To your problem: For some reason IE doesn't like a variable to be called `length`. Its probably colliding with a property of the same name. Try renaming it.